# Nginx cache : return cached response AND forward request to backend server also

Tags: caching, nginx, proxy, varnish

I want to use nginx cache (or varnish) in front of a web server (nginx).

The content of the database are modified once a day, so the response time can be significantly improved by serving a cached result. However the backend server still needs to receive and track each & every request in real time.

As a result, the cache won't reduce the load on the backend server because it'll still process & track the request, but the response to the client would be much faster.

Is it possible to do it in nginx or varnish ? 
(i.e. return cached response to the client instantly AND forward the request to the backend server at the same time).

Comment: what do you mean by _backend server still needs to receive and track every request in real time_? Cache on proxy level reduces complexity O(n) to O(1), cache on backend still gives you O(n) but you save computation resources by storing processed data.

Comment: @Anatoly Even if the request is found in cache, I want the backend server to receive the request (it's a design requirement : the server performs statistical analysis on the requests for a different part of the website). The purpose of the cache is to speed up response for the client.

Comment: in that case from proxy layer each of these requests is no different, implement the caching logic on the application side

Comment: Caching in front of webserver would return response faster. Anyways, is that possible at all i.e. return response from cache AND forward request to backend ?